# Textbox on a Winforms panel is not selectable, editable

Tags: winforms, textbox, telerik, panel, locked

I have a requirement to make an existing app allow users to select the text in a display field. I.e.:

**Label: Textbox that should be selectable**

I've been through most of the app, and usually it's as simple as converting a label to a textbox and making it readonly.

However, there's one form where those display fields ARE textboxes, yet when putting a cursor on them, it doesn't switch to a vertical bar, and you cannot select the text.

The textboxes are on a panel, which is on a Telerik PageView control.

I recall from ages ago that there's something about layers on a WinForm, and that textboxes become uneditable/unselectable if they're on another grouping control, like a panel. Can't locate anything about that now. Nothing is disabled or otherwise locked.

Google has not been my friend with this. Does anyone have suggestions on what might be going on here? Thanks.

(Visual Studio 2015, VB.NET)

Comment: What is the expected behavior for the control exactly? What the users should be able to do with the control? What they should not be able to do?

Comment: The previous controls were labels. A label ignores attempts to select and copy. Textboxes don't. The requirement is that those fields (hard to figure out what to call them in this case) should be copy-able by dragging or double clicking and Ctrl+C.

Comment: And what's the problem with `TextBox`?

Comment: The controls in question are Textboxes. Default behavior when double-clicking a word, or clicking and dragging in a textbox is that that text obeys rules of Ctrl+C. 

Say there's quite a bit of text there, and it contains a string of random characters (like an ID). Currently, users have to type out that text manually in whatever thing they want to copy to, say a Notepad file. They would like to select the text, and copy it, and then paste it in to the destination. These textboxes don't allow that behavior.

Comment: I couldn't understand what's the problem with `TextBox`. It's unclear for me what you are asking. You said expected behavior is users can copy text from the control. `TextBox` has this feature.

Comment: Yes, but THESE particular textboxes don't exhibit that behavior. I think it may have something to do with the container controls they're inside.

Comment: No, it's not related to the container.

Comment: Which part of expected behavior doesn't work? It doesn't show right click menu? Or when you double click on the  text it doesn't select the word? or something else?

Comment: Stackoverflow is suggesting I move this to chat, but before I do that, I'll just point out that these textboxes are behaving like labels. You can't select and copy a label. You can select and copy text in a textbox. I can't select and copy stuff from these textboxes.

Comment: Why don't you put together a small sample/snippet demonstrating the undesired behavior so we can have a look at it?